# @Size annotation not recognized (JPA)

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

I want to validate the length of a String before trying to insert/update the entity to the Database.

```
@Size(min = 1, max = 45)
@Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 45)
private String name;
```

My problem is the @Size annotation is not being recognized using NetBeans 7.3, JDK 1.6, EclipseLink (JPA 2.0).

Is there an alternative to this ?

Comment: Because it is nothing to do with the JPA API perhaps? It is the Bean Validation API

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to include

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```