# @Size annotation, Hibernate JPA creates different DDL in Java Application and Web managed bean execution environments

Tags: hibernate, jpa, size, ddl

I know there is a similar question ([@Size annotation not recognized (JPA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19566447/size-annotation-not-recognized-jpa)) but I think the given solutions does not explain this matter.

I don't want to duplicate annotations @Column(length) (for JPA scope) and @Size(max) (for Bean validation scope). So I try to use only @Size annotation for both scenarios.

I have a simple entity with a field that has the @Size(max=50) annotation, I also use lombok utility (https://projectlombok.org) for simplifying setters and getters.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "myentity", schema = "util")
@NoArgsConstructor()
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {

  @Getter @Id  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Short id; 

  /** attribute that contains the description, unique value*/
  @Size(max = 50) @NotNull () @Column(unique = true) @Getter @Setter
  private String description;
}
```

I have a simple class to bootstrap Hibernate and create the schemas. It contains the @Named and @SessionScoped annotations. It also contains a main method. So that it can be executed both as a Java application and as a managed bean in JSF. Here is the code

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
@NoArgsConstructor
public class HibernateBootstrap implements Serializable{

  public String updateSchema() {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("control_post");  
    emf.close();
    return "OK";
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     new HibernateBootstrap().updateSchema();
  }

}
```

A simple xhtml file is included to call the updateSchema method

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">  
  <h:head>  
  </h:head>  

  <h:body>  
    <h:form>  
      <p:commandButton value="Create Tables" action="#{hibernateBootstrap.updateSchema}"/>
    </h:form>
  </h:body>  
</html>
```

When I execute the HibernateBootstrap.main method as a Java Application, I get this DDL sentence in the console

```
create table util.myentity (id  serial not null, description varchar(255), primary key (id))
```

But when I execute the xhtml file to Run on Server and press the button "Create Tables", this DDL sentence is generated (that takes into account the @Size(max) annotation:

```
create table util.myentity (id  serial not null, description varchar(50) not null, primary key (id))
```

If you want to see the persistence.xml, here is the code. Thanks

```
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">

  <persistence-unit name="control_post" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect"    value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />                 
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb" />
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="user" />
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password" /> 
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Comment: `@Size` is a Bean Validation API annotation, not part of the JPA API. JPA has `@Column(length=...)` for schema generation. Use that and you ought to get predictable behaviour. Why do you create an EntityManager, never use it, and then dont close it?!!!

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I apologize for my low-level in Java programming.  I agree with you in the fact that I don't need to create an EntityManager for schema generation. I also agree that the @Column(length=..) is in the JPA API. But does anybody know why the DDL sentences generated when running on server take into account Bean Validation annotations? Thanks

Comment: I have edited the post to delete the unnecessary EntityManager creation.